# Excel VBA: How to only allow macro to make cell input

Tags: excel, vba, user-input, readonly, worksheet

I'm currently working on a worksheet, which should use different userforms to perform tasks and calculations. The userforms are called via buttons.

So all the input by the user should be made via those userforms; the actual worksheet should contain only the results which should be read-only (for the user).

Problems:

1. Protecting the worksheet will also prevent the macro from making changes.
2. The following code has the same issue as protecting the worksheet.

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
           Target.Clear
           MsgBox "SomeAlertMSG"
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

Any suggestions how to accomplish this without using self-made boolean flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for here is the `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` flag for protecting sheets in VBA.

Protect your sheet from VBA by the following line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Protect Password:="123", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

This will protect the sheet and prevent the user from editing it manually, however any macros can still change the sheet! Obviously you can choose a different password, or have it as an input so it's not baked in/visible in your code.

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx

> *UserInterfaceOnly* - True to protect the user interface, but not macros. If this argument is omitted, protection applies both to macros and to the user interface.

Answer (score 2):

Call another sub to write to the range for you and handle events like so:

```
Sub WriteToCell(ByVal cell As Excel.Range, ByVal cellValue)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        cell.Value = cellValue
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Then in your userform when you want to write something to a range just write:

```
WriteToCell Sheets("someSheet").Range("A1"), "I can stay here!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your worksheet unprotected by using the below code in the code to be executed after clicking on macro.

```
Sheet1.Protect Password:="Secret"
```

After the code is executed then the sheet will get locked again.